# My programs doesn't return 0 when deleting array pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, runtime-error

When I try to delete array pointer which declared like

```
short *width = NULL;
width = new short[lenght];
delete[] width;
```

the programs stop at delete part and returns a random number.

here is my all program

```
int main(){
    short **junction = NULL, *width = NULL, length = 0;
    ifstream input;

    input.open("sample_input.txt");
    if(!input)
        cout << "No such a file named \"sample_input.txt\"" << endl;
    else if(input >> length){
        junction = new short*[length];
        width = new short[length];
        string str; 
        for(int i = 0; i - 1 < length && getline(input, str); i++){
            istringstream ss(str);
            width[i - 1] = (str.size() + 1) / 2; //numbers can be two char, so in this case, here we allocate more than necessary memory
            junction[i - 1] = new short[width[i - 1]];
            for(int j = 0; j < width[i - 1]; j++){
                if(ss.eof()){
                    junction[i - 1][j] = -1; // -1 is the key value of emtpy spaces
                    continue;
                }
                ss >> junction[i - 1][j];
            }
        }
    }
    input.close();

    /*
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        delete[] junction[i];
    delete[] junction;
    delete[] width;
    */

    return 0;
}
```

the comment part makes problem, I tried those delete statements seperately
just for part is runing but not as I expected
here is my sample input:
[image: sample input]

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with the shown code. The problem lies in the context that you are not showing. Please provide a proper [mre] for your problem. See also [ask].

Comment: You can't have this kind of code at the global scope.

Comment: Please reduce your code to the minimal amount necessary to reproduce the issue. In particular avoid having all the file IO in there. If it is unavoidable to reproduce the issue, then specify the contents of the file as well.

Comment: That said, what index of the array do you expect `width[i - 1]` to access in the first loop iteration where `i` is `0`? It seems to me your program has undefined behavior whether or not you are adding the commented part at the end.

Comment: Yeah, but when I typed 'width[i]' width[0] not assigned, I think reason of this is 'getline(input, str)' part, I check the index of the width its fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be actually fine. Please show us the whole program.

```
florian@florian-desktop:~$ cat -n test2.cpp
     1  #include <iostream>
     2  int main()
     3  {
     4  const int length = 4;
     5  short *width = NULL;
     6  width = new short[length];
     7  delete[] width;
     8  }
florian@florian-desktop:~$ valgrind ./a.out 
==22630== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==22630== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==22630== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==22630== Command: ./a.out
==22630== 
==22630== 
==22630== HEAP SUMMARY:
==22630==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22630==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 72,712 bytes allocated
==22630== 
==22630== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==22630== 
==22630== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==22630== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Valgrind shows that all reserved memory is correctly released.

### --
Updated:

I corrected your full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
short **junction = NULL, *width = NULL, length = 12;
    ifstream input;

    input.open("sample_input.txt");
    if(!input)
        cout << "No such a file named \"sample_input.txt\"" << endl;
    else if(input >> length){
        junction = new short*[length];
        width = new short[length];
        string str; 
        for(int i = 0; i < length && getline(input, str); i++){
            istringstream ss(str);
            width[i] = (str.size() + 1) / 2; //numbers can be two char, so in this case, here we allocate more than necessary memory
            junction[i] = new short[width[i]];
            for(int j = 0; j < width[i]; j++){
                if(ss.eof()){
                    junction[i][j] = -1; // -1 is the key value of emtpy spaces
                    continue;
                }
                ss >> junction[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    input.close();

    
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        delete[] junction[i];
    delete[] junction;
    delete[] width;
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: just updated the code, what do you think now. I spend my hours to see anything bad in the code

Comment: 11
2 4 5
1
5 6
1 5 8
1 3 4
3 7 10
6 11
4 9
8 10
6 9
7
this is sample data but system wrtie those on the same line

Comment: Your mean issue is that you messed up the indices. If you access width[i - 1] and i is 0, a memory error occurs because the first valid index in width is 0. I fixed your code now and it seems to behave fine.. At least, the memory accesses are correct now and all reserved memory is being free'd. Please always write the full code.